# Javascript color display

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to create an HTML file from a js file using node.js! My question is why do the colors not display in the html file. I created the string for the hex values, but in the html file the colors are not shown.

```
var format;
function RND() {
var hex = ((Math.floor(Math.random()*0xffffff)+1)).toString(16);
while (hex.length < 6) hex = "0" + hex;
 return "#"+hex;
}
console.log("<html><head>");
console.log("<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">");
console.log("<title>Ten Random Colors</title>");
console.log("</head>");
console.log("<body>");
console.log("<ul>");
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
var color = RND();
//console.log(color);
format="<li style =\""+color+"\">"+color+"</li>";
console.log(format);
}
console.log("</ul>");
console.log("</body>");
console.log("</html>");
```

Comment: Hopefully you're not expecting the colors to show up in the console ?

Comment: No, using node.js  I can send the output to an HTML document so it just basically outputs everything in quotes to create a html document.

Comment: Works fine, but you're outputting 100 colors, not 10.

Comment: Build a single string than output it....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the CSS key,

change this

```
format="<li style =\""+color+"\">"+color+"</li>";
```

to this

```
format = "<li style =\"color : " + color + "\">" + color + "</li>";
```

What you you had would give you

```
<li style="#ffffff">#ffffff</li>
```

which is not valid

Comment: OMFG DUDE IT WORKED!!! THANK YOU SO MUCH!! I've been trying to solve this problem for a few days now!! =) =) =)

Comment: Accepted! It made me wait 6 minutes before I could accept it as an answer! Thank all you guys again!!